# filter rdd based on timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a following code :-

```
val imei = "86656"
val date = "2017-04-09"
val gpsdt = "2017-04-09 00:20:10"
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "xyz").select("id", "date", "dttime").where("id=? and date=?", imei, date)
```

So, now I have rdd which brings the entire data of particular imei of specific date but I want to filter rows to get 2 rows based on the mentioned "gpsdt" - 1 row just greater then the given time and 2nd Row just less then the mentioned row? How Can I achieve that ?

My Cassandra DB Schema is :-

```
create table xyz( id text,date text, dttime timestamp,roll text, primary key((id,date),dttime)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can **separate the rdd into two** :

***1*** with `dttime` greater than `gpsdt`, order by `dttime` in ascending order and `take` the first one.

***2*** with `dttime` less than `gpsdt`, order by `dttime` in descending order and `take` the first one.

And finally `union` them and you should have your desired rows

**programmatically**

```
val justGreater = rdd.filter(row => row.get[String]("dttime") > gpsdt).sortBy(row => row.get[String]("dttime")).take(1)
val justLess = rdd.filter(row => row.get[String]("dttime") < gpsdt).sortBy(row => row.get[String]("dttime"), false).take(1)
justGreater.union(justLess)
```

Thanks to @Alex Ott for pointing out to https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md

Comment: `cassandraTable` returns RDD, not DataFrame! See https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md

Comment: @Ramesh, I'm getting error :- value $ is not a member of StringContext &

Comment: after import My error message changed to :-

type mismatch; found : org.apache.spark.sql.Column required: com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow ⇒ Boolean

Comment: @RameshMaharjan - After editing your answer, I know the steps but I need some query or commands that I can use because I'm unable to find greater then or less then on RDD . If you can provide me with Query that will be helpful . Thanks,

Comment: Giving an error :- value getAs is not a member of com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow

Comment: On using get - I got this error - not enough arguments for method get: (implicit c: com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter[T])T. Unspecified value parameter c.

Comment: are you still available on chat ?

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt for pointing out my mistake and giving the link so that I could help the OP

Comment: Much Thanks to @RameshMaharjan for your precious time and helping me out this issue. Cheers ... :)

Comment: My please @AdityaJain and thanks for upvote and acceptance and Thanks to Alex